# Logs not getting pushed to logEntries

Tags: docker, logging, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, logentries

We are having docker containers running on Amazon ECS. These docker containers are pushing logs to logEntries via logEntries token. We are seeing that the logs are getting pushed to logEntries whenever the container is restarted and after sometime the logs are not being pushed to logEntries. Although the container is running.

Can someone provide the flow of how logs are pushed from container to logEntries.